# Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException when deploying Spring Boot WAR file on Websphere Application server 9.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2, thymeleaf, websphere-9

I am trying to deploy my spring boot application on WebSphere 9 but it is giving me: Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /myapp/Welcome
Url used: http://localhost:9080/test/myapp/Welcome

Below are my changes for request mapping.

Class level mapping: @RequestMapping("/myapp")
Method level mapping :  @GetMapping("/Welcome")  // which returns the Html page Welcome.html

Added the context root in pom.xml

WAS9.0 admin console changes

1. Setting the context path as /test
2. Setting the class loading order
   After installing war. Click on war application-> class loading and update detection -> class loading with local class loader first (parent last)

When i am trying to hit the http://localhost:9080/test/myapp/Welcome url the server giving: Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /myapp/Welcome

Please help on this to resolve

Comment: Why are you deploying a Spring Boot app into WebSphere? No need for WebSphere; it can run by itself serving web pages, REST services, connect to the database, etc. It's not a natural fit, and could become overly complex to transfigure it to fit inside WebShere.